# Set column value to 0 if date is older than

Tags: mysql

I wonder is it possible to set certain column value to 0 (column name `up` in the example) query if one of it's column's. For example column named dateExpire have date less than some other date... This is how I imagine query would look like.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_news [ IF dateExpire <= now() THEN set up=0 ] ORDER BY up DESC
```

Comment: Did you try executing it ?

Comment: No.. It's just example how I think it might look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found ansewer by myself.

```
SELECT *, IF(dateExpire >= now(), up, up= 0) as up FROM tbl_news ORDER BY up DESC
```

Comment: where are u updating the vaue of up?

Comment: I see you understand PHP, so I'll show you how this would look like in PHP, so.. `This IF(dateExpire >= now(), up, up= 0)` in PHP would look like `if($dateExpire => now()) { $up=$up; } else { $up=0; }`

Answer (score 0):

update tbl_news set up=0 where dateExpire <= now()

as per my understanding..